# Read tab delimited file to Structure in C

Tags: c, file, input, struct, csv

I have a file with tab delimited data. I want to read the every line into a Structure. I have a code to read the data to char buffer. But I want to load the data into a Structure.

This is My sample data.

> empname1\t001\t35\tcity1
>
> empname2\t002\t35\tcity2

My Structure definition .

```
struct employee
{
  char *empname;
  char *empid;
  int age;
  char *addr;

};
```

My sample program to read data to a `char` array `buffer`

```
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];      /* Character buffer */
    input_fd = open (fSource, O_RDONLY);
    if (input_fd == -1) {
       perror ("open");
        return 2;
    }
                    
    while((ret_in = read (input_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
                    
         // Do Some Process 
    }
```

Here I want to load the content to a structure variable instead of the character buffer. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, a possible solution could be

1. Read a complete line from the file using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. tokenize the input buffer based on the required delimiter [`tab` in your case] using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).
3. allocate memory ([`malloc()`/ `realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)) to a pointer variable of your structure.
4. copy the tokenized inputs into the member variables.

<sup>Note:
1. `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing `\n`.
2. Please check carefully how to use `strtok()`. The input *string* should be mutable.
3. Allocate memory to pointers before using them. IMO, use statically allocated array as `struct employee` member variables.</sup>

Comment: It would be easy to remove the trailing `newline` with `strtok(buffer, "\t\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fscanf function. Open a file as a stream then use the fscanf to get a input from the file.

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
FILE *fp=fopen(fsource,"r+");
struct employee detail;
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %s",detail.empname,detail.empid,&detail.age,detail.addr);
```

Make sure that allocation of memory to the variables.

Or else you can use the `strtok` function. That time you have to use the sscanf function.

Comment: Using any of the `scanf()` functions will be hard. The only way to force them to respect tabs as field boundaries is with the `%[…]` scan set conversion specification, which this answer does not currently use.

Comment: Your `fscanf` will read the **whole** of each line into the first `%s` ie. `detail.empname`, Its not going to tokenise on itself, usage of `fscanf` is incorect. Demo : http://ideone.com/3zKWI6. Sidenote: `detail.age` should be `&detail.age` in `fscanf`.

Comment: In your input we have to give the tab space not \t. I taken \t from question as a tab specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fscanf` to read each line from file, `strtok` to tokenize the *line* read.
Since your structure members are pointers, allocate memory appropriately.

The following minimal code does exactly what you want.

```
#define SIZE 50 
FILE *fp = NULL;                                                            
int i = 0;                                                                  
struct employee var = {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL};                                
char line[SIZE] = {0}, *ptr = NULL;   

/* 1. Open file for Reading */                                                 
if (NULL == (fp = fopen("file.txt","r")))                                   
{                                                                           
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");                              
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                     
}
```

---

```
/* 2. Allocate Memory */                                                       
var.empname = malloc(SIZE);                                                 
var.empid = malloc(SIZE);                                                   
var.addr = malloc(SIZE);
```

---

```
/* 3. Read each line from the file */   
while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%s", line))                                       
{                                                                           
    /* 4. Tokenise the read line, using "\" delimiter*/                     
    ptr = strtok(line, "\\");                                                                                   
    var.empname = ptr;                                                      

    while (NULL != (ptr = strtok(NULL, "\\")))                              
    {                                                                       
        i++;                                                                

        /* 5. Store the tokens as per structure members , where (i==0) is first member and so on.. */
        if(i == 1)                                                          
            var.empid = ptr;                                                
        else if(i == 2)                                                     
            var.age = atoi(ptr);                                            
        else if (i == 3)                                                    
            var.addr = ptr;                                                 
    }                                                                       

    i = 0;        /* Reset value of i */                                                          
    printf("After Reading: Name:[%s] Id:[%s] Age:[%d] Addr:[%s]\n", var.empname, var.empid, var.age, var.addr);
}
```

Working Demo: http://ideone.com/Kp9mzN

Few things to Note here:

1. This is guaranteed to work, as long as your structure definition (and order of members) remains the same (see manipulation of value `i`).
2. `strtok(line, "\\");`, Second argument is just escaping (first `\`) the actual `\` character.

---

Clarification from the OP:

In your structure definition, *third* member is an `int`, however you're trying to read `t35` into it (which is a *string*).
So `var.age = atoi(ptr);` will give you `0`,

You could change the structure definition, making third member as `char *` and allocating memory like other members.

Or change file contents, making sure an `int` is present as the third value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you are looking for

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

struct employee
{
char *empname;
char *empid;
int age;
char *addr;

};

int readEmploee(char *line, struct employee *employee)
{
    char *token;
    char *saveptr;
    char *endptr;

    if ((employee == NULL) || (line == NULL))
        return 0;

    token = strtok_r(line, "\t", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return 0;
    employee->empname = strdup(token);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\t", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return 0;
    employee->empid = strdup(token);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\t", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return 0;
    employee->age = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
        return 0;

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\t", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return 0;
    employee->addr = strdup(token);

    return 1;
}

char *mygetline(int fd)
{
    char  *line;
    size_t length;
    size_t count;
    char   character;

    line = malloc(128);
    if (line == NULL)
        return NULL;
    length = 0;
    count  = 1;
    do
    {
        if (read(fd, &character, 1) != 1) /* end of file probably reached */
        {
            free(line);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (character != '\n')
        {
            if (length > 128 * count)
            {
                char *temp;
                temp = realloc(line, 128 * count);
                if (temp == NULL)
                {
                    free(line);
                    return NULL;
                }
                line   = temp;
                count += 1;
            }
            line[length++] = character;
        }
    } while (character != '\n');
    line[length] = 0;

    return line;
}

struct employee *readFile(const char *const fSource, size_t *count)
{
    struct employee *employees;
    int              employeeCount;
    int              input_fd;
    char            *line;

    if ((count == NULL) || (fSource == NULL))
        return NULL;

    *count        = 0;
    employees     = NULL;
    employeeCount = 0;
    input_fd      = open (fSource, O_RDONLY);
    if (input_fd == -1)
    {
        perror ("open");
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((line = mygetline(input_fd)) != NULL)
    {
        struct employee employee;
        if (readEmploee(line, &employee) != 0)
        {
            struct employee *temp;

            temp = realloc(employees, (1 + employeeCount) * sizeof(struct employee));
            if (temp != NULL)
                employees = temp;
            employees[employeeCount++] = employee;
        }
        free(line);
    }
    *count = employeeCount;

    return employees;
}

int
main()
{
    size_t           count;
    size_t           index;
    struct employee *employees;

    employees = readFile("somesamplefile.txt", &count);
    if (employees == NULL)
        return 1;
    for (index = 0 ; index < count ; index++)
    {
        struct employee current;

        current = employees[index];

        fprintf(stderr, "%s, %s, %d, %s\n", current.empname, current.empid, current.age, current.addr);
        if (current.empname != NULL)
            free(current.empname);
        if (current.empid != NULL)
            free(current.empid);
        if (current.addr != NULL)
            free(current.addr);
    }
    free(employees);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, you should assume that names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation.  The details are a little more nuanced than that, but not enough to make it wise to use such names in your own code.

Comment: Sorry, bad habit. Fixed it. Thank you.